# Splitting combined columns in select statement

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, select

I'm using a select statement that combines two columns, EmployerID and Name as such:

```
SELECT EmployerID + '-' + Name AS CompanyName FROM Employer
```

to be put into a drop down list from the database. 
I have no issue selecting and filling the database, however, I need to use the EmployerID which is a foreign key of the Employee entity to select respective employees that belong to said employer by using

```
string x =ddlEmployer.SelectedValue.ToString();
SqlCommand EmployeeCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT EmployeeNo + ' - ' + Name As EmployeeName From Employee Where EmployerID = @SelectEmployer", conn);
EmployeeCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SelectEmployer", x);
```

I cannot select it as doing a select statement of the selected value using the CompanyName combined values would not return anything be it making it equals or like as shown above.

So my question is, after selecting these two and displaying them as a single option in a dropdownlist, how would I then use the selected value to search for the EmployerID that is supposed to exist?

Comment: Have you tried `string x = ddlEmployer.SelectedValue.ToString().Split('-')[0];`?

Comment: adding more to @hendryanw comment, if you are aware of type of x, then you can use `EmployeeCmd.Parameters.Add("@SelectEmployer", <Type casting operation>);` and if you are not aware of type then prefer to use `AddWithValue`

Answer (score 2):

First, change your initial query to include the EmployerID.

```
SELECT EmployerID + '-' + Name AS CompanyName, EmployerID FROM Employer
```

Then bind the correct columns to the DropDownList. You can have two different column, one for the TextField and one for the ValueField.

```
DropDownList1.DataSource = source;
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "CompanyName";
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "EmployerID";
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Now you always have the EmployerID as the SelectedValue.

```
EmployeeCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SelectEmployer", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix this with hendryanw's comment which was to simply use

```
string x = ddlEmployer.SelectedValue.ToString().Split('-)[0];
```

which helps to split it and select the index I want, works both ways.

Comment: Good for you. If you have more time, you should try to learn what VDWWD suggested in his answer. That's the way it should be done and it's always good to understand how to use a tool properly.